# Passing model object between views django (Object is not JSON serializable)

Tags: json, django, object, serialization, model

I've made model objects for my forms (Didn't use form models) and I want the user to progressively fill out the model as they go through the different web pages (views). To do this I need to obviously pass the model object through views. I've already tried sessions as you'll see below however the model object is not JSON Serializable. Is there anyway I can get around this?

```
def home(request):
    request.session['client'] = user_information(answers=personal_injury_answers())
    return render(request, 'homescreen.html')


def firstStep(request):
    client = request.session['client']

    if request.method == 'POST':
        preliminary_user_info = dict(QueryDict(query_string=request.body))
        client.zipcode = int(preliminary_user_info['identifier'][1])
        print(client.zipcode)
        if preliminary_user_info['identifier'][0] == 'personal_injury':
            return redirect('piuserform')
        else:
            return redirect('home')
```

Comment: 'Object of type 'user_information' is not JSON serializable' is the error I'm getting when I try to use request.session. user_information is a model object

Comment: Edit your question to include the whole error message **with full traceback** please.